# Scripted dataloader error: Expected 5000 to be processed for batch but got results for 4000

Tags: data-loader, upsert, commandline

We have few jobs scheduled on data loader, we are receiving the error in the sdl.log file:

> Expected 5000 to be processed for batch but got results for 4000

Relevant portion log is given below

```
2016-10-17 10:00:43,681 INFO  [OrderLineItemUpsert] progress.NihilistProgressAdapter setSubTask (NihilistProgressAdapter.java:78) - Processed 1,361,110 of 1,399,110 total records. Rate: -298,000 records per hour. Estimated time to complete: 39 minutes and 13 seconds.  There are 871,232 successes and 489,878 errors.
.
.
.
2016-10-17 10:00:53,853 INFO  [OrderLineItemUpsert] visitor.BulkApiVisitorUtil updateJobStatus (BulkApiVisitorUtil.java:179) - Batch Status: 0 Queued, 3 In Progress, 249 Completed, 28 Failed.
2016-10-17 10:03:36,748 INFO  [OrderLineItemUpsert] progress.NihilistProgressAdapter setSubTask (NihilistProgressAdapter.java:78) - Processed 1,364,110 of 1,399,110 total records. Rate: -283,000 records per hour. Estimated time to complete: 40 minutes and 38 seconds.  There are 873,972 successes and 490,138 errors.
2016-10-17 10:03:36,748 INFO  [OrderLineItemUpsert] visitor.BulkApiVisitorUtil updateJobStatus (BulkApiVisitorUtil.java:179) - Batch Status: 0 Queued, 0 In Progress, 251 Completed, 29 Failed.
2016-10-17 10:03:36,748 INFO  [OrderLineItemUpsert] progress.NihilistProgressAdapter setSubTask (NihilistProgressAdapter.java:78) - Retrieving Bulk Job Results
2016-10-17 10:03:38,029 ERROR [OrderLineItemUpsert] action.AbstractAction handleException (AbstractAction.java:199) - Exception occured during loading
com.salesforce.dataloader.exception.LoadException: 7511A000007OurvQAC: Expected 5000 to be processed for batch but got results for 4000
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.action.visitor.BulkLoadVisitor.sanityCheckError(BulkLoadVisitor.java:436)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.action.visitor.BulkLoadVisitor.sanityCheckBatch(BulkLoadVisitor.java:424)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.action.visitor.BulkLoadVisitor.processResults(BulkLoadVisitor.java:305)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.action.visitor.BulkLoadVisitor.getResults(BulkLoadVisitor.java:292)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.action.visitor.BulkLoadVisitor.flushRemaining(BulkLoadVisitor.java:270)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.action.AbstractLoadAction.flush(AbstractLoadAction.java:86)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:126)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.executeAction(Controller.java:120)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:149)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:100)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.main(ProcessRunner.java:253)
2016-10-17 10:03:38,045 ERROR [OrderLineItemUpsert] progress.NihilistProgressAdapter doneError (NihilistProgressAdapter.java:58) - 7511A000007OurvQAC: Expected 5000 to be processed for batch but got results for 4000
```

It appears the data loader was running successfully but throws error suddenly and Error/Success files show not record nor they are updated in the system. I have not come across that kind of an error before, any idea or help from the community would be appreciated.

P.S. Bulk API is enabled for this particular data load job.

Answer (score 0):

The log indicated that there are "490,138 errors". You don't see any of those logged in the failure log?

The subsequent "Expected 5000 to be processed for batch but got results for 4000" is likely just a symptom of the 490K of errors.